# Validating multiple checkboxes laravel 5.2

Tags: php, validation, laravel, checkbox, laravel-5

I am trying to validate checkboxes in my Laravel application. The HTML name and values of the checkbox are generated from my database and I am doing a loop to display all the boxes. How do I do a validation rule so that at least one box is checked or required? These are the relevant view code from my blade file and the method from my controller.

```
//Snippet from create-user.blade.php
<div class='form-group'>
    @foreach ($roles as $role) //$role variable gets its data from the db
    {{ Form::label('role', $role->display_name) }}
    {{ Form::checkbox($role->name, $role->id) }}
    @endforeach
</div>

//Snippet from UserController.php
public function addUser(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'=>'required|max:120|alpha_dash',
        'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
        $role->name =>'required', //This line results in 'Undefined variable: role'
        'password'=>'required|min:4',
        'password_confirmation'=>'required|min:4']
    );
    $email = $request['email'];
    $name = $request['name'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);
    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $email;
    $user->name = $name;
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('account');
}
```

What do I pass in place of `$role->name` in the validation array?
Thanks

Comment: Try to see the output of `$request->all()` via `Log::error()` method...you will see that based on your checkbox names there will be multiple items in the array..you need to loop that array and validation each field separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating checkbox with name of role, better create checkbox with static name like `roles[]`. I modified your code, have a look. Also added roles attach to user (I assuming You already have `roles` relationship in `User` model).

```
//Snippet from create-user.blade.php
<div class='form-group'>
    @foreach ($roles as $role) //$role variable gets its data from the db
    {{ Form::label('roles', $role->display_name) }}
    {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id) }}
    @endforeach
</div>

//Snippet from UserController.php
public function addUser(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'name'                  => 'required|max:120|alpha_dash',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'roles'                 => 'required',
            'password'              => 'required|min:4',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:4'
        ]
    );
    $email          = $request['email'];
    $name           = $request['name'];
    $password       = bcrypt($request['password']);
    $user           = new User();
    $user->email    = $email;
    $user->name     = $name;
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->save();

    //attach roles
    $user->roles()->sync($request->input('roles',[]));

    return redirect()->route('account');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked partially. Now both check boxes are checked automatically even when I select just one, after submitting the form. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Sorry, left a small error in script: `{{ Form::checkbox('roles', $role->id) }}` should be `{{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id) }}`. Then You will post array if roles ids to controller and it should work as You want.